# Resource management on spark standalone

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm running on spark 1.4.0, and I have a cluster of 10 executors, with 4 cores each (40 cores in total)

I have 5 applications (and probably more in the future)I want to run, I submit them using scheduler (each application runs every 2-5 hours) -

2 applications are more important, and I want them to have 50% of my resources
2 application I want to run with 25% of my resources
1 application I want to run with 10% of my resources

The number of total cores is currently 40, but it might change from time to time if I add more slaves, and I don't want to change the submit script every time I add a slave

I'm not sure how to configure my spark-submit call, so it won't give me the message:

```
org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl- Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: one important comment - I'm running on spark standalone version

Answer (score 0):

From the current (1.4.0) Spark documentation:

> The standalone cluster mode currently only supports a simple FIFO scheduler across applications. However, to allow multiple concurrent users, you can control the maximum number of resources each application will use. By default, it will acquire all cores in the cluster, which only makes sense if you just run one application at a time. You can cap the number of cores by setting spark.cores.max in your SparkConf.

If you wan't more advanced control you may wish to consider using Yarn or Mesos.